# TensorFlow 2.5 update in Colab breaks keras code

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I have been running several deep learning models in google colab using Keras.
My codes worked perfectly but suddenly, today, a lot of errors appeared reporting problemas with the imports. Pasting one here.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-745bb0894037> in <module>()
     19 from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
     20 from keras.utils import np_utils
---> 21 from keras_contrib.applications.densenet import DenseNetFCN
     22 from keras_contrib.losses.jaccard import jaccard_distance

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_contrib/applications/densenet.py in <module>()
     66 from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
     67 from keras.regularizers import l2
---> 68 from keras.utils.layer_utils import convert_all_kernels_in_model
     69 from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
     70 from keras.engine.topology import get_source_inputs

ImportError: cannot import name 'convert_all_kernels_in_model' from 'keras.utils.layer_utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/layer_utils.py)
```

Comment: Yes Keras is broken in Colab, they updated Keras to an unreleased version and it is broken, so far no fix is known other than downgrading tensorflow and keras to a version that your code supports.

Answer (score 1):

so I am answering my question for anyone who might have trouble with it.
They updated Tensorflow and Keras in Colab to 2.5 versions, and some functions are not migrated (i.e. convert_all_kernels_in_model).
For me, the solution was to paste the code of the NN architecture and comment the line with that function as I was not using it.
I know it is not the best solution but it got me through what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The final release of TensorFlow version 2.5 requires a nightly dev build of keras that seems to be the source of these issues.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.5.0/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/setup.py#L107

The relevant TensorFlow issue to report your experience is:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/49823

Comment: And how could I use this version in colab?